# Django Forms Show Extra Categories For Users Part Of Group

Tags: python, django, forms, view, model

I'd like to show these categories below additionally with users who have the blogger category.

The current issue is..

1. For a blogger user it's only showing blogger categories when it should be showing all
2. For a normal user it's showing blogger categories when it should only be showing the original 3

forms.py

```
class PostCreateForm(ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            "title",
            "category",
            "associated_portfolios",
            "body",

        ]
        exclude = ('allow_comments',)
        

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        blogger = User.objects.filter(groups__name='blogger').exists()
        print("Current User:", user)
        print("Blogger User:",  blogger)

        super(PostCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'].choices = (
                ("Watchlist", "Watchlist"),
                ("Lesson/Review", "Lesson/Review"),
                ("General", "General"),
                )
        if User.objects.filter(groups__name='blogger').exists():
            self.fields['category'].choices = (
                ("Analysis", "Analysis"),
                ("Milestone", "Milestone"),
                ("Features", "Features"),
                ("Tutorials", "Tutorials"),
                ("Careers", "Careers"),
                ("Community", "Community"),
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the following
def **init**(self, *args, **kwargs):
user = kwargs.pop('user', None)

```
super(PostCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

if user and user.groups.filter(name = 'blogger').exists():
    # show all categories if user is in blogger group
    self.fields['category'].choices = (
        ("Analysis", "Analysis"),
        ("Milestone", "Milestone"),
        ("Features", "Features"),
        ("Tutorials", "Tutorials"),
        ("Careers", "Careers"),
        ("Community", "Community"),

        ("Watchlist", "Watchlist"),
        ("Lesson/Review", "Lesson/Review"),
        ("General", "General"),
    )
else:
    # show basic categories if user is not in blogger group.

    self.fields['category'].choices = (
        ("Watchlist", "Watchlist"),
        ("Lesson/Review", "Lesson/Review"),
        ("General", "General"),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

check user is in the group and show categories for blogger

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user', None)

    super(PostCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    if user and user.groups.filter(name = 'blogger').exists():
        # show all categories if user is in blogger group
        self.fields['category'].choices = (
            ("Analysis", "Analysis"),
            ("Milestone", "Milestone"),
            ("Features", "Features"),
            ("Tutorials", "Tutorials"),
            ("Careers", "Careers"),
            ("Community", "Community"),
        )
    else:
        # show basic categories if user is not in blogger group.

        self.fields['category'].choices = (
            ("Watchlist", "Watchlist"),
            ("Lesson/Review", "Lesson/Review"),
            ("General", "General"),
        )
```

Comment: oh my answer is like yours. sorry i think you wrote User.groups.filter(name = 'blogger') with capital U in user and that seamed to me odd.

Comment: Not getting any errors but also not showing the blogger categories to blogger user

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if user is in group blogger and base on that show him diffrent categories you should do it like that:

```
class PostCreateForm(ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            "title",
            "category",
            "associated_portfolios",
            "body",

        ]
        exclude = ('allow_comments',)
        

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        # blogger = User.objects.filter(groups__name='blogger').exists()
        # print("Current User:", user)
        # print("Blogger User:",  blogger)

        super(PostCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        if User.objects.filter(groups__name='blogger', id=user.id).exists():
            self.fields['category'].choices = (
                ("Analysis", "Analysis"),
                ("Milestone", "Milestone"),
                ("Features", "Features"),
                ("Tutorials", "Tutorials"),
                ("Careers", "Careers"),
                ("Community", "Community"),
            )
        else:
            self.fields['category'].choices = (
                ("Watchlist", "Watchlist"),
                ("Lesson/Review", "Lesson/Review"),
                ("General", "General"),
                )
```

You need to check if user that is passed to form in kwargs have blogger group. Even better than:

```
User.objects.filter(groups__name='blogger', id=user.id).exists()
```

is use

```
user.groups.filter(name='blogger').exists()
```

directly on User instance

Comment: user.groups.filter(name='blogger').exists() gives me a 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups' error and the first solution is giving me a 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id' error